# Use Requests instead of PyCurl, login with cookies

Tags: python, curl, authentication, python-requests, pycurl

I actually use pycurl for requests to a specific site.

https://uniparthenope.esse3.cineca.it/

The login method isn't by post request.

I use pycurl in this way:

```
page = BytesIO()
        cookie=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        print(cookie.name)
        c = Curl()
        c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, page.write)
        c.setopt(c.COOKIEJAR,cookie.name)
        c.setopt(c.URL, url)
        c.perform()
        c.close()
        page.close()

        page = BytesIO()
        c = Curl()
        c.setopt(c.USERPWD, self.__username + ":" + self.__password)
        c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, page.write)
        c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE,cookie.name)
        c.setopt(c.ENCODING, encoding)
        c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, httpheader)
        c.setopt(c.REFERER, url)
        c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, useragent)
        c.setopt(c.URL, url)
        c.perform()
```

With the first pycurl request I take the cookie and store it in a temporary file, with the second pycurl request I do the login.
How I can do this with Requests?
I already tried requests.session but no result...

Thanks in advance